# Android Studio - orientation of Fragments when using Navigation graph / component

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, orientation

Okay - I have same issue as quite a few others have had in the past - and there are plenty of posts with the solution, but somehow the solution doesn't work for me.

In Android Studio (Bumblebee - 2021.1.1 Patch 3) - I am using the Navigation Component for my fragments - and all the fragments are displayed in Portrait mode - and I want them in Landscape mode.

The solution I found quite a few times is apparently to press the letter 'o' and the display orientation of the fragments should change.
However, when I press 'o' (lowercase or uppercase), nothing changes.

Note: When I am viewing an individual fragment xml file, pressing 'o' does flip the orientation, but pressing 'o' has no effect when viewing the fragment navigation in my navigation.xml file.

I tried clicking on different areas of the IDE window before pressing 'o', but still no success.
Can anyone help me please?